# How can I download many links in the same time using FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, download, links, help-files

Is it possible to use `ffmpeg -i -c copy` with several links at once?

Comment: Good question. I'm currently doing that by running multiple instances of ffmpeg at the same time. If I could do them all in one command, that would be really nice.

Comment: I believe the basic format you likely want is `ffmpeg -i input1 -i input2 -map 0:v -map 0:a -c copy output1 -map 1:v -map 1:a -c copy output2`, where ex. `-map 0` corresponds to the first input, `-map 1` corresponds to the second input, etc.